# iCal Event and Reminder backup and restore

Tags: ios, iphone

Application needs to backup calendar events and  reminders, i tried using iCloud backup , but its backups all application data.

My requirement is to backup and restore iCal data only. 
Is it possible using iCloud ? 
I need to create my own program for backup restore process?
Any other way?

Comment: Please show us what have you tried till now

Comment: I tried default iCloud backup and restore process, not use any program.Please check below link http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1766

Comment: Is it possible using iCloud?